# Subdivision Surface messing up image texture?

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv, modifiers, subdivision-surface

I am currently modelling in blender and have created my own image texture in photoshop. Here is the version withouth subdivision surface:

[image]

Here with SS turned on:
[image]

As you can see, it looks very weird in regions where multiple vertices are in the same spot (I used that to create the triangular shape of the wings). I've gone through all settings in the SS menu, but none could help.

I've also made sure that the image texture covers all faces that it should completely, so this cannot be the issue.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, but having multiple verticies may be the problem. Merge them `Alt` + `M` and then see what the results are.

Some other things to consider are what your edge flow is like at those positions. If there are no edge creases or loop cuts, then the subdivision modifier may *round* your objects at those locations. With lighting, normals etc, this may be giving you that appearance?

Comment: thanks, this solved the issue! I always thought that you shouldn't have triangular faces, this is why I did it like that